# "New API In version A.B.C" page in doxygen

Tags: versioning, doxygen

There is a Doxygen option to specify when API appeared using `\since` tag, for example

```
///
/// Does foo
///
/// \since 1.5
///
void foo();
```

And it would appear in `foo()`'s documentation.

What I'm looking is a way to create automatically page that contains all API
appeared in 1.5 - i.e. list all API marked by `\since 1.5` or probably
some other tag if available.

**Edit:** I tried to use `\ingroup` and create a group page containing all new API there and it works. But it moves description to this page, for example moves a new method from class definition to a page "New in 1.2.3" which isn't what I wanted.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want to create an e**x**ternal **ref**erence to the current **item**, an [`\xrefitem`](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdxrefitem):

```
\xrefitem version_change_1_0_0 "Since 1.0.0" "Changes in 1.0.0" ...
             <key>               <heading>    <list title>      <text>
```

All items that share the same `<key>` will be shown on a special generated page. The `<heading>` will be used to start a section at the place you're *using* `\xrefitem`, whereas `<list title>` will be used as a title for the resulting page (see remarks below). The text can be arbitrary.

The result you get is similar to the lists and appearances of`\todo` and `\bug`, and you can even think of `\bug` and `\todo` implemented as

```
\bug  <text> = \xrefitem bug  "Bug"  "List of bugs" <text>
\todo <text> = \xrefitem todo "Todo" "List of todos" <text>
```

Unfortunately, the key [cannot contain dots:](https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/blob/3fbb1b66bd5303fa789a36317694bd77eb22ee19/src/doctokenizer.l#L334)

```
ID        "$"?[a-z_A-Z\x80-\xFF][a-z_A-Z0-9\x80-\xFF]*
LABELID   [a-z_A-Z\x80-\xFF][a-z_A-Z0-9\x80-\xFF\-]*
```

Therefore, you have to use an alias that takes (at least) two arguments, one for the label, and one for the actual text:

```
ALIASES += sinceversion{3}="\xrefitem version_changes\1 \"Since \2\" \"Changes in \2\" \3\n\n"
ALIASES += sinceversion{2}="\sinceversion{\1,\2,Introduced in this version.}"
```

If you never use dots, you can of course simplify the alias even more. This will give you two new commands:

- `\sinceversion{label, version}`
- `\sinceversion{label, version, custom text}`

In both cases, the label must only contain alphanumeric symbols, the version can be arbitrary. If you don't provide the custom text, "Introduced in this version" will  be shown.

If there's a page with the identifier `version_changes<label>`, the list of changes will be added. Note that the `\page`'s title will overwrite the title given by the `\xrefitem`, which can be handy for major releases.

## Example

Here's an example of `\sinceversion`'s usage. Note that you probably want to use another alias like `ALIASES += since_vXYZ{1}="\sinceversion{X_Y_Z,X.Y.Z,\1}"` if you document a lot of changes for version x.y.z:

### Example code

```
/** Foos around.
 * \sinceversion{001,0.0.1}
*/
void foo(){}

/** Bars around.
 * \sinceversion{001,0.0.1}
 * \sinceversion{002,0.0.2,Removed a memory leak}
*/
void bar(){}

/** \page version_changes002 Changes in 0.0.2
  *
  * We found several memory leaks and removed them
 */
```

### List of version change pages

[image: list of change pages]

### List of changes per version

[image: list of changes per version]

### List of changes per version with additional description

[image: description and list]

### Appearance of changes in function documentation

[image: references in function descriptions]

Comment: Actually I did something simpler:

`ALIASES += ver{1}="\ref \1\n \xrefitem \1 \"\" \"\""` so in every location I write \ver{v1_2_3} and created a page `\page v1_2_3 New in Foo 1.2.3` so I get both label and page.

Great thanks xrefitem is exactly what I was looking for!